# Multiple Forms with JSF 2.2

Tags: jsf-2, myfaces

I have a JSF page with two forms

I use JSF 2.2 with MyFaces Implementation

Show the next examples (xhtml and ManagedBean)

When i press add Item(doNew) Button, the input shows the correct value; after i press Back (doCancel) Button, and press add Item(doNew) again.

The value of input exampleBean.newBean.descripcion shows the old description, when i pressed the first one. But the output #{exampleBean.newBean.descripcion}" always shows the correct value. If i use only one form the issue works well buy i need understand why does not work with two forms?

Regards,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:body>

<h:form styleClass="horizontal-form form-search" id="form1">
    <h:messages></h:messages>

    <h:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-default btn-success"
        value="Add Item" action="#{exampleBean.doNew}">

    </h:commandButton>

</h:form>


<h:form id="form2">
    <h:messages></h:messages>

    <h:outputText value="#{exampleBean.newBean.descripcion}"></h:outputText>
    <h:inputText value="#{exampleBean.newBean.descripcion}" id="input1234"></h:inputText>

    <h:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-default btn-default"
        value="Back" action="#{exampleBean.doCancel}"
        immediate="true">
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

And my ManagedBean is

```
@ManagedBean(name = "exampleBean")
@ViewScoped
public class ExampleManagedBean {
    private Object newBean;
protected String panelMode = null;

public ExampleManagedBean() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    panelMode = "default";

    newBean = new Concepto();
}

public String doCancel() {
    panelMode = "default";
    return null;
}

public String doNew() {
    panelMode = "edit";
    Concepto c1 = new Concepto();
    c1.setDescripcion("descripcion " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    newBean = c1;
    return null;
}

public Object getNewBean() {
    return newBean;
}

public void setNewBean(Object newBean) {
    this.newBean = newBean;
}

public String getPanelMode() {
    return panelMode;
}

public void setPanelMode(String panelMode) {
    this.panelMode = panelMode;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The commandButton submits the values ​​of its form. And it doesn't see the values ​​of other form.

So in your case, you have to put your commandButton in the same form of the value to add.

*The form tag renders an HTML form element. JSF forms use the "post-back" technique **to submit form data back to the page** that contains the form.*

http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_form.html

Comment: Yes, but the input value is retrieved from the action. why works the first time? and why the output text shows correctly? the renders output and input are different for the same object.

Comment: Please try you test without

     immediate="true"

And Check if your getting right value in your managedBean when your submit by Button Back